# Joda-time: how to normalize ReadablePartial to expected fields?

Tags: java, jodatime

I want a functionality that let the caller selectively set some fields, but some of the `ReadablePartial` implementation does not "normalize" automatically. For example, if you set the "year" field in the `Partial` class, the "year of era" field is not readable.

I can cope with the fields year, month, day, hour, minute. Is there any call(s) that will do the normalization to these fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the following hack using normalization code built into the Period class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Partial pa = new Partial().with(DateTimeFieldType.halfdayOfDay(), 1).with(DateTimeFieldType.hourOfHalfday(), 3)
            .with(DateTimeFieldType.minuteOfHour(), 34);
    Period pr = new Period(zeroWithMatchingFields(pa), pa);
    p(pr.getHours()); // Returns 15
}

public static Partial zeroWithMatchingFields(ReadablePartial in) {
    AbstractPartial ap = in instanceof AbstractPartial ? (AbstractPartial) in : new Partial(in);
    int[] zeros = new int[ap.size()];
    return new Partial(ap.getFieldTypes(), zeros, in.getChronology());
}
```